# Count the number of Occurences of duplicates R Code

Tags: r, duplicates

I need a line of code that will search a vector of numbers and return the number of occurrences.  For Example

```
a=c(15,32,27, 63, 15,99, 32,32)

dup=unique(a[duplicated(V.Ints)])
len=length(unique(duplicated(dup)))
```

I get:

```
> dup
#[1] 15, 32

> len
#[1] 2
```

but what I need is:

```
> dup
#[1] 15, 32

> len
#[1] 5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Arun's suggestion in the comments is the way to go:

```
> sum(a %in% c(15,32))
#[1] 5
```

For more general usage:

```
sum(a %in% unique(a[duplicated(a)]))
```

Or a one-liner in the spirit of Mr Flick's approach:

```
sum(a %in% names(which(table(a) > 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count frequencies with

```
table(a)
# a
# 15 27 32 63 99 
#  2  1  3  1  1
```

You can filter to find only the duplicates

```
Filter(function(x) x>1, table(a))
# a
# 15 32 
#  2  3 
names(Filter(function(x) x>1, table(a)))
# [1] "15" "32"
```

and you can take the sum to find the total length of duplicates

```
sum(Filter(function(x) x>1, table(a)))
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation is to grab all the duplicated values then use `length()` for `len` and `unique()` for `dup`

```
x <- a[duplicated(a) | duplicated(a, fromLast=TRUE)]

length(x)
# [1] 5
unique(x)
# [1] 15 32
```